# Redirect url clashes with flask-;login

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I currently have a flask server and an angular js front end on which users can buy things from third party vendors.

These third party vendors have their own payment gateways to which I connect my front end to... So at the point of making the payment, we redirect the user to the payment gateway... Once a payment is made, we have a redirect url on our flask servers that captures the success message (and the payment details).

The issue here is that since we do it on the front end (and since this is a third party's website), the flask-login does not seem to work.  We use session to store some of the data of the purchase and thus, we cant seem to be able to connect the product the customer has bought with the transaction he made to buy it!

I have given my apis below:

```
@api.route('/quoteRequest/',methods = ['POST'])
# @flask_login.login_required
def carquote():
    data = request.get_json()
    c = quoteController.FUTGENGI(data = data, lob = "Motor", stage="quote")
    d = c.finOutput
    finalQuotes = []
    finalQuotes.append(d)
    return Response(json.dumps(finalQuotes),mimetype = "application/json")
@api.route("/proposalRequest/",methods = ['POST'])
def proposalRequest():
    data = request.get_json()
    current_app.logger.debug(data)
    c = quoteController.FUTGENGI(data = data, lob = "Motor", stage="proposal")
    output = json.loads(c.quoteDict)
    session['proposal'][data['Quote']['insurerID']] = data
    return Response(json.dumps(output),mimetype = "application/json")


#Redirect URL:
@api.route('/FUTGENGI/policyCreate/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def policyCreate(insurerID):
    if request.method == "GET":
        par = OrderedDict(
        WS_P_ID = request.args.get('TranID')
        TID = request.args.get('UID')
        PGID = request.args.get('PaymentID')
        Premium = request.args.get('Amt')
        Response = request.args.get('Response')
        )
        if(par['Response'] == "Success"):
            for k,v in par.items():
                session['proposal']['FUTGENGI'][k] = v
            c = quoteController.FUTGENGI(data = session['proposal']['FUTGENGI'], lob = "Motor", stage="payment")
            return Response(json.dumps(c.paymentOutput), mimetype = "application/json")
        else:
            return Response(json.dumps({"output":"Oops.  Something went wrong.  Please try again"}), mimetype = "application/json")
```